# Match word in String in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match Strings that contain the word `"#SP"` (sans quotes, case insensitive) in Java. However, I'm finding using Regexes very difficult!

Strings I need to match:
`"This is a sample #sp string"`, 
`"#SP string text..."`, 
`"String text #Sp"`

Strings I do not want to match: 
`"Anything with #Spider"`,
`"#Spin #Spoon #SPORK"`

Here's what I have so far: http://ideone.com/B7hHkR .Could someone guide me through building my regexp?

I've also tried: `"\\w*\\s*#sp\\w*\\s*"` to no avail.

Edit: Here's the code from IDEone:

```
java.util.regex.Pattern p = 
    java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("\\b#SP\\b", 
        java.util.regex.Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

java.util.regex.Matcher m = p.matcher("s #SP s");

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Match!");
}
```

Comment: `*` in a regex means "zero or more times".

Comment: @BrianRoach I thought I was using it correctly. For example:

`"This is a #sp"` (more than 0 times before #sp, 0 times after #sp),


`"#sp text"` (0 times before #sp, more than 0 times after),

`"#sp"` (0 times before and after)

Comment: With regexes, you only need to match the text you want to match. Do not have concern about what is before or after what you want to match, except if you explicitly need to. And this is where anchors come into play as well, since they do not consume text: `\\b` will detect a "word boundary", but will not consume the character before/after the word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing fine, but the \b in front of the # is misleading.  \b is a word boundary, but # is already not a word character (i.e. it isn't in the set [0-9A-Za-z_]).  Therefore, the space before the # isn't considered a word boundary.  Change to:

```
java.util.regex.Pattern p = 
    java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(^|\\s)#SP\\b", 
        java.util.regex.Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

The (^|\s) means: match either ^ OR \s, where ^ means the beginning of your string (e.g. "#SP String"), and \s means a whitespace character.

Comment: You're welcome.  Apparently you do need the change to find() rather than matches(), as fge said.  He taught us both something today.

Answer (score 6):

(edit: positive lookbehind not needed, only matching is done, not replacement)

You are yet another victim of Java's misnamed regex matching methods.

`.matches()` quite unfortunately so tries to match the *whole input*, which is a clear violation of the definition of "regex matching" (a regex can match anywhere in the input). The method you need to use is `.find()`.

This is a braindead API, and unfortunately Java is not the only language having such misguided method names. Python also pleads guilty.

Also, you have the problem that `\\b` will detect on word boundaries and `#` is not part of a word. You need to use an alternation detecting either the beginning of input or a space.

Your code would need to look like this (non fully qualified classes):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^|\\s)#SP\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

Matcher m = p.matcher("s #SP s");

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Match!");
}
```

Comment: What does the "?<=^" part mean?

Comment: Thank you very much. But please allow me to understand your regexp: `?<=^` means match "?, <, =, or nothing"?

Comment: `(?<=...)` is a positive lookbehind. It is an anchor which means "try and start matching the regex if what is before it matches the given regex (`...`). Admittedly, here it was not needed since only a match is needed and nothing is replaced, so `(^|\\s)` was enough.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression `"\\w*\\s*#sp\\w*\s*"` will match 0 or more words, followed by 0 or more spaces, followed by #sp, followed by 0 or more words, followed by 0 or more spaces.  My suggestion is to not use \s* to break words up in your expression, instead, use \b.

```
"(^|\b)#sp(\b|$)"
```

Comment: Here's the result of using `"\b#SP\b"`: http://ideone.com/DF1dPq

 It still doesn't match the String.

Comment: For some reason, the \b word boundary in Java is not matching the beginning or end of the string.  I've edited my answer to accomodate this.